# ADF : GoButton javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, managed-bean, propertynotfoundexception

I'm trying to implement a `goButton` in JDeveloper and I want that the `url` will be `dynamic` and will by taken from several input texts, but when I calling to a function in java class

```
public class reportAction {

    private static final String LOG = "reportAction --------------------> ";

    private BindingContainer bindings;

    public String createURL(){
        bindings = getBindings();
        AttributeBinding test = (AttributeBinding) bindings.get("DesformatName");
        System.out.println(LOG + test);
        return test.toString();
    }
}
```

and I put the method in the destination value `(destination="#{reportAction.createURL}")` I get the `PropertyNotFoundException`

Why?

---

**Edit**:

I'm trying to build a dynamic url within a managed bean and call it with a POST method. The goal is to click the goButton and call the bean by set the destination property value to that bean. I've defined a managed bean and set it to backingBeanScope in the adf-config.

Answer (score 0):

The JSF component attribute needs to refer to a String property in a managed bean that has getter/setter.

Try having the bean structured like:

```
public class reportAction {

    private BindingContainer bindings;
    private String createURL = "";

    public String getCreateURL(){
        bindings = getBindings();
        AttributeBinding test = (AttributeBinding) bindings.get("DesformatName");
        System.out.println(LOG + test);
        return test.toString();
    }
}
```

Also - check if changing the bean scope to be view scope helps.